# Insert Query executing on local DB but not on server

Tags: mariadb

I'm facing a strange error. I have a 5.5.5-10.1.20-MariaDB install on my local mac (brew) and a 5.5.52-MariaDB on my prod server (centos7). My local DB content is a copy from my server DB. I've executed this query on local:

```
## CREATE DIRECT RELATION BETWEEN JOURNAL AND PUBLICATION
INSERT INTO journal_publication (journal_id, `publication_id`) (
select issues.journal_id as journal_id, publications.id as publication_id from issues
join publications on issues.id = publications.`issue_id`
where publications.id Not In (select distinct publication_id from journal_publication)
);
```

It works fine and takes only less than a second to execute.
Now when I try the exact same query on my prod server, the query is never ending and takes all CPUs. Moreover, I've tried to EXPLAIN the query, it works fine on my local:

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   PRIMARY issues  index   PRIMARY issues_journal_id_foreign   5   NULL    70993   Using index; Using temporary
1   PRIMARY publications    ref publications_issue_id_foreign   publications_issue_id_foreign   5   pubpeer.issues.id   1   Using where; Using index
2   MATERIALIZED    journal_publication index   NULL    PRIMARY 8   NULL    143926  Using index
```

Whereas the same query on my Prod returns an error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO journal_publication (journal_id, `publication_id`) 
(select issues.j' at line 2
```

Again, the content of the two DBs are identical, primary keys and indexes are set equally. For the record, when I try and execute this query:

```
select issues.journal_id as journal_id, publications.id as publication_id from issues
join publications on issues.id = publications.`issue_id`
where publications.id Not In (select distinct publication_id from journal_publication;
```

either on local or prod takes only a second.

Have you got any clue or process I could follow to help me understand these differences?

Thanks.

Xavier

Comment: The error message says that something right before `INSERT` caused trouble.  Check the whitespace for stuff that works on one OS but croaks on other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- MariaDB server versions < 10.0 only support `EXPLAIN SELECT`
- MariaDB server versions >= 10.0 support additionally `EXPLAIN
  UPDATE`, `EXPLAIN INSERT` and  `EXPLAIN DELETE`

Please note that the version string 5.5.5-10.1.20-MariaDB means MariaDB 10.1.20, the 5.5.5 prefix is required since MySQL replication would break, since it supports only 1 digit numbers for the major version.

See also [EXPLAIN UDATE/INSERT/DELETE in MySQL and MariaDB](http://s.petrunia.net/blog/?p=85)